# Counting comparisons in quicksort

Tags: c++, c, quicksort, counting

I am trying to calculate number of comparisons for `quicksort`. For the worst case scenario, it shows n*n-1/2 comparisons. So for 8 inputs in the order 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1, it should be 28 comparisons. However, in my program there are 30 comparisons. I tried to print comparisons and all were fine but the last comparison is repeated thrice. Anyone could find the fault with this code?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int ar[10000];
int pivot;
int temp;
int partition(int x, int y);
void quicksort(int f, int l);
int count = 0;
int i;
int index;
void main() {
  clrscr();
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    cin >> ar[i];
  }
  quicksort(0, 7);
  cout << "\nThe sum is  " << sum;
  getch();
}
void quicksort(int f, int l) {
  if (f == l)
    return 0;
  if (f < l) {
    pivot = partition(f, l);
    quicksort(f, pivot - 1);
    quicksort(pivot + 1, l);
  }
}
int partition(int f, int l) {
  index = ar[f];
  i = f + 1;
  for (int j = f + 1; j <= l; ++j) {
    if (ar[j] < index) {
      temp = ar[j];
      ar[j] = ar[i];
      ar[i] = temp;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  i = i - 1;
  temp = ar[f];
  ar[f] = ar[i];
  ar[i] = temp;
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be doing 28 to me - see http://ideone.com/i0XmDA

Comment: Your code is uncommented, has terse and unclear variable names,  and is full of globals (!); that needs addressing.  Cleaner code would be easier to debug -- a sound reason for doing it.  (Another is it'll make other programmers more willing to read your code!)

Answer (score 0):

You can also using the STL sorter of an arbitrary container with a comparator that simply counts the comparisons.

```
class LessCompare
{
  public: 
    LessCompare() : m_counter ( 0u ) {}

    template<typename T>
    bool operator() ( T const& lhs, T const& rhs ) const {
      ++m_counter;
       return lhs < rhs;
    }

    unsigned compares() const { return m_counter; }

  private:
   unsigend m_counter;
};

std::vector < T > container;
LessCompare compare;
std::sort ( container.begin(), container.end(), std::ref ( compare ) );
std::cout << "Compares: " << compare.compares() << std::endl;
```

However, I'm pretty unsure whether `std::sort` is an quicksort.

You can simply improve your *quicksort* that uses an arbitrary *functor* that do the comparison and counts some statistics.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of HP / Microsoft's std::sort, if in debug mode, there are two extra compares done to check if the compare is "<" and not "<=". It does this by checking a < b, then b < a. If you're building in debug mode, try building in release mode instead and see if it helps.